In Angular 17, trying to clean an input after the user arrives in the page via back button generates non-coherent values
In my Angular 17 project, I have a page that does a redirect.
I want to be able to clean an input field if the user press the back button after the redirect as the browser (Chrome) is maintaining the old values.
Searching a lot I found this solution to clean the field:
@ViewChild('iptUrl')
set watch(iptUrl: ElementRef) {
    if (iptUrl) {
        console.log('test1', iptUrl);
        console.log('test2', '#' + iptUrl.nativeElement.value + '#');

     // iptUrl.nativeElement.value = '';
     // The above line is what I would do to clean the input. 
     // It's commented so it doesn't interfere in the debugs.

    }
}

But I'm getting an irrational output from the debugs:
When I expand in the console, the  iptUrl object from the first console.log (test1) the property iptUrl.nativeElement is reporting that the value is "https://192.168.0.155:4200/feee5230". Correct. The old value I want to clean. But the 2nd console.log (test2) is returing '##'.
If I try to do iptUrl.nativeElement.value = ''; as I would want nothing happens and the input maintains the old value :/
If I try JSON.stringify(iptUrl) this is the result in the console:
{"nativeElement":{"__ngContext__":8,"__zone_symbol__inputfalse":[{"type":"eventTask","state":"scheduled","source":"HTMLInputElement.addEventListener:input","zone":"angular","runCount":0}],"__zone_symbol__blurfalse":[{"type":"eventTask","state":"scheduled","source":"HTMLInputElement.addEventListener:blur","zone":"angular","runCount":0}],"__zone_symbol__compositionstartfalse":[{"type":"eventTask","state":"scheduled","source":"HTMLInputElement.addEventListener:compositionstart","zone":"angular","runCount":0}],"__zone_symbol__compositionendfalse":[{"type":"eventTask","state":"scheduled","source":"HTMLInputElement.addEventListener:compositionend","zone":"angular","runCount":0}],"__zone_symbol__ngModelChangefalse":[{"type":"eventTask","state":"scheduled","source":"HTMLInputElement.addEventListener:ngModelChange","zone":"angular","runCount":0}],"__zone_symbol__keyupfalse":[{"type":"eventTask","state":"scheduled","source":"HTMLInputElement.addEventListener:keyup","zone":"angular","runCount":0}]}}
No value property.
Here's an image of the output of both console.log debugs above:

What's happening here ?
This is the definition of the input in the template:
<input [(ngModel)]="url" (keyup)="validate($event)" #iptUrl id="iptUrl" class="form-control form-control-lg empty" type="text" placeholder="Write here!" aria-label="Write here!" required>

If anyone has a better method to clean this input, the answer would also be accepted.
Thanks.
Edit
Just to clarify, I'm pretty sure that the component's url property is set to an empty string. Proof:
If I try to do:
@ViewChild('iptUrl')
set watch(iptUrl: ElementRef) {
    if (iptUrl) {
        console.log('test1', iptUrl);
        console.log('test2', '#' + iptUrl.nativeElement.value + '#');
        console.log('test3', '%' + this.url + '%');
                    
        //          iptUrl.nativeElement.value = '';
        //          window.iptUrl.value = '';
    }
}

this is the result:


The simplest solution is to force a refresh when back button is pressed, since SPA applications like angular, have issue with back button.
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@HostListener('window:pageshow', ['$event'])
onPopState(event) {
  location.reload()
}


I've been in this problem for some hours now. I've tried all that. Here's a paste.bin of my (now commented) OnInit debugs. I also had tried OnDestroy and router events. OnDestroy didn't work,  Router Events does nothing as the code in the question. The input somehow receives the value in a way not tied to the component. It's probably some background render from the browser itself. Changing the linked property of the component does nothing as it's already an empty string.

See my edit on the question

@NelsonTeixeira updated my answer with new approach

popstate didn't work. But pageshow and load worked. That solved the situation. One good thing would be editing the answer from popstate to pageshow and deleting the other non-working tests in order not to mislead other readers.
Thanks for taking me out of a 4 hours head banging :)

Just for completition sake, I didn't do a location.reload(). I did this: if (this.iptUrl !== undefined) this.iptUrl.nativeElement.value = '';, iptUrl is defined as: ViewChild('iptUrl') iptUrl: ElementRef | undefined;
